# Eloquent и тип vabinary

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

у меня такой вопрос.
Я пытаюсь сделать кастомную регистрацию в Laravel, но мое поле password имеет тип varbinary(16), из за этого не получается создать пользователя.

Вот мой код

`{return UserAuth::create([`

```
        'account' => $data['account'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы поле password создавалось в varbinary, как я могу это сделать? Изменить тип поля в бд я не могу, нужен именно varbinary.

Использую MsSql server 2008. Спасибо.

Если меняю тип на varchar и сохраняю туда хеш, то все работает прекрасно, но это мне не подходит.

Comment: А какую ошибку хоть выдаёт, когда пользователя создаёте?

Comment: @VladimirGonchar [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to binary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте преобразовать пароль в нужный тип через `DB::raw()`:

```
UserAuth::create([
    'account' => $data['account'],
    'password' => DB:raw('CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), "'. bcrypt($data['password']) .'", 1)'),
]);
```

Comment: теперь выдает такое [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'y$10$3ZQaUkPMOoYc3toT61'

Comment: Двойные кавычки добавьте чтобы обернуть строку bcrypt в SQL запросе с обеих сторон.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov а не подскажете, где именно, что то я не поняла)

Comment: @WelcomeMaster Поправил в ответе

Comment: @VladimirGonchar теперь почему то выдает неверное название строки Invalid column name '$2y$10$9Lspkj5zGYkkWCbxglWqO.hB5/X6PErQmc9HzkIm1XFuyt1AbdhDG'.

Comment: Cпасибо большое за помощь, в итоге все получилось, когда привела строку к следующему виду. Плюс сменила хэш на мд5. DB::raw('CONVERT(binary, 0x'. md5($data['password'], false) .')')